# Do I need to grant EXECUTE rights on a function that is called from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-permissions

I have a SQL function that is *only* called from inside another stored procedure. I have granted EXECUTE rights for the stored procedure that calls the function.

Do I need to grant EXECUTE permissions to the function as well?

**EDIT**

*In response to the comment from @AaronBertrand*

The function does not access any other objects in the database. It is used to build a string.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: true, but the syntax is `GRANT  EXECUTE  ON ...`. That's what I meant.

Comment: Again, it depends on what the function accesses, the rights of the user calling the stored procedure, etc. Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I have updated my answer with more information that you requested. I dropped the function and recreated it (to remove any permissions that might have been associated with the function) and it seems to work.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Do you want to put your comment as an answer so I can give you credit? I don't like having unanswered questions .... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that your user can't execute it, try dropping and re-creating the function, and applying the appropriate permissions on the function itself and any object(s) it references. There may be a `DENY` hanging around, which will always trump `GRANT`.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that in my specific case because the function does not access any other objects in the DB, no rights needs to be assigned.